# Selenium Webdriver (java) Test

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to verify  when a user clicks on a book title at the bottom panel he will be taken to Amazon site and it will display book with the same title.

Driver.findElement(By.linkText("**Master of the Game**")).click();
 Now Amazon page will be open with :**Master of the Game** by Sidney Sheldon  (Author)

Comment: You'll need to search for some element on the page with the text that you want or you can also verify the url

Comment: where is the issue..where is exception?

Answer (score 0):

You've got the first part down..

`driver.findElement(By.linkText("Master of the Game")).click()`

The second part is to validate.  If by "page will be open" you mean, the title is "Master of the Game by Sidney Sheldon", then that's simple:

```
if (!driver.getTitle().equals("Master of the Game by Sidney Sheldon")) {
  // test fails
} else {
  // test passes
}
```

Comment: Doesn't actually verify that the landing page is an Amazon one. Should probably also mention waiting until the page has fully loaded before doing the assert, or else waiting until the title actually matches.

Comment: well given the information from the OP, that's the best I got.  There is a reason that the question was downvoted.  there really isn't enough information to work with, but i did what i could with what i had.

Comment: All true - just thought I'd put it down for future generations.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to click on the link text which you can achieve in several ways by different different locators.

Like as you mentioned you can do

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Master of the Game")).click()

Then you can check whether the new amazon page is loading in the same page or new page by

```
  driver.getWindowHandles().length()
```

if the length is `one`

```
if (!driver.getTitle().equals("Master of the Game by Sidney Sheldon")) {
  // test fails
} else {
  // test passes
}
```

if the length is `two`

you can try

```
for (handle : driver.getWindowHandles)
{
 driver.switchTo(handle);

}
```

Since there are just 2 windows when it will come out of the loop your control will be on the 2nd page,

and again you can do your validation with

```
if (!driver.getTitle().equals("Master of the Game by Sidney Sheldon")) {
      // test fails
    } else {
      // test passes
    }
```

Please check the actual methods a i have not used editor so some changes may be required in the code.